# pgfplots legend nested in matrix

Tags: pgfplots, legend, tikz-matrix

I'm using a `\matrix` to arrange subplots, each created using pgfplots.  When I tried to use `\legend` to add a legend to individual plots, lualatex tells me

> Package pgf Error: You cannot nest pgfmatrix environments, yet.

How can I label my barseries on a subplot?  A combined legend for all subplots is also ok, provided that I can prevent series in different subplots from reusing colors (but I'd prefer not to explicitly choose colors).

---

My current code looks like

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering 
   \tikzset{external/export=false}
\resizebox{.9 \columnwidth}{!}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \matrix[ampersand replacement=]{
       \begin{axis}[
         y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
         ybar,
         ymin=0, ymax=100, ylabel={\%}, table/y index=2
       ]
         \addplot table[header=false,row sep=\\] { 8 5 2.0833 \\ 9 48 20.0000 \\ 10 187 77.9167 \\ };
         \addplot table[header=false,row sep=\\] { 8 6 2.5000 \\ 9 65 27.0833 \\ 10 169 70.4167 \\ };

         \legend{Series A, Series B}
       \end{axis}
       \pgfmatrixnextcell
       \begin{axis}[
         y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
         ybar,
         yticklabel pos=right,
         ymin=0, ymax=100, ylabel={\%}, table/y index=2
       ]
          \addplot table[header=false,row sep=\\] { 37 2 0.8333 \\ 38 3 1.2500 \\ 39 5 2.0833 \\ 40 0 0.0000 \\ 41 7 2.9167 \\ 42 5 2.0833 \\ 43 7 2.9167 \\ 44 7 2.9167 \\ 45 7 2.9167 \\ 46 8 3.3333 \\ 47 9 3.7500 \\ 48 16 6.6667 \\ 49 20 8.3333 \\ 50 13 5.4167 \\ 51 15 6.2500 \\ 52 12 5.0000 \\ 53 11 4.5833 \\ 54 12 5.0000 \\ 55 18 7.5000 \\ 56 7 2.9167 \\ 57 14 5.8333 \\ 58 16 6.6667 \\ 59 5 2.0833 \\ 60 10 4.1667 \\ 61 1 0.4167 \\ 62 4 1.6667 \\ 63 3 1.2500 \\ 64 0 0.0000 \\ 65 1 0.4167 \\ 66 0 0.0000 \\ 67 1 0.4167 \\ 68 0 0.0000 \\ 69 0 0.0000 \\ 70 0 0.0000 \\ 71 1 0.4167 \\ };
          \addplot table[header=false,row sep=\\] { 30 2 0.8333 \\ 31 1 0.4167 \\ 32 2 0.8333 \\ 33 4 1.6667 \\ 34 4 1.6667 \\ 35 3 1.2500 \\ 36 4 1.6667 \\ 37 6 2.5000 \\ 38 5 2.0833 \\ 39 7 2.9167 \\ 40 19 7.9167 \\ 41 17 7.0833 \\ 42 15 6.2500 \\ 43 18 7.5000 \\ 44 11 4.5833 \\ 45 17 7.0833 \\ 46 17 7.0833 \\ 47 14 5.8333 \\ 48 10 4.1667 \\ 49 11 4.5833 \\ 50 8 3.3333 \\ 51 11 4.5833 \\ 52 2 0.8333 \\ 53 7 2.9167 \\ 54 11 4.5833 \\ 55 3 1.2500 \\ 56 4 1.6667 \\ 57 1 0.4167 \\ 58 1 0.4167 \\ 59 2 0.8333 \\ 60 2 0.8333 \\ 61 0 0.0000 \\ 62 0 0.0000 \\ 63 0 0.0000 \\ 64 1 0.4167 \\ };
       \end{axis}
         \\
     };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
   \caption{Yup, a caption}
   \label{plot:unique_plot_name}
\end{figure}
```

The datapoints actually are stored in data files autogenerated from MATLAB scripts, and pulled in via `\input`.  So that's why the plot settings are set on the axis.  But this seems unrelated to my legend problems.

---

Hmm, tex.se just suggested [How can I add a legend in aligned subplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67515/how-can-i-add-a-legend-in-aligned-subplots)

Using `pgfplotslibrary{groupplots}` and some tweaking of settings, I've achieved

[image]

I'd like to use bars for the right-hand plot also, but they overlap by default and I'm still trying to configure family of figures, not individually control each one.

Comment: It looks like maybe I should be using groupplot instead of matrix.  Off to try some things...

Comment: Well, `groupplot` has worked out really well for everything but my histogram-using-ybar... still fiddling.

Comment: Could you please give a schematic plot (sample out put or something similar to what you want)? Because for my thesis, I plotted a matrix organized plot. If I see something similar to yours, I may be able to help you.

Comment: The legend is a matrix on its own, and these cannot be nested (a limitation of PGF). You may be able to use `legend to name` in order to _separate_ the legend from the axis and to draw it at a "suitable" place using the associated `\ref` command. Details about this approach can be found in the manual; search for `legend to name`...

Comment: I think groupplot is adequate for these too.  And I found `cycle list shift` which should lead to unique styling for the second subplot

Comment: @BenVoigt Could you please update your question, adding that plot to your post?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Thanks for that, if I encounter something where groupplot isn't sufficient I'll definitely try that scheme.  I think you can go ahead and mark this as a duplicate of the linked question, since its answer got me unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

I plotted something similar to what you want using pgfplots. You can edit the legend transparency and its location to best fit what your plot you want to look like.

```
%pdflatex
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    ybar stacked,
    title=Bar plot,
    samples=50,point meta rel=axis wide,
    point meta=y,
    legend style={at={(0.075,0.75)},anchor=south west},
    ]
    \addplot table[header=false,row sep=\\] { 8 5 2.0833 \\ 9 48 20.0000 \\ 10 187 77.9167 \\ };
    \addplot table[header=false,row sep=\\] { 8 6 2.5000 \\ 9 65 27.0833 \\ 10 169 70.4167 \\ };
    \legend{Group A, Group B}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
~
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    title=Line Plot,
    samples=50,
    point meta rel=per plot,
    point meta=y,
    legend style={at={(0.075,0.75)},anchor=south west},
    ]
    \addplot table[header=false,row sep=\\] { 37 2 0.8333 \\ 38 3 1.2500 \\ 39 5 2.0833 \\ 40 0 0.0000 \\ 41 7 2.9167 \\ 42 5 2.0833 \\ 43 7 2.9167 \\ 44 7 2.9167 \\ 45 7 2.9167 \\ 46 8 3.3333 \\ 47 9 3.7500 \\ 48 16 6.6667 \\ 49 20 8.3333 \\ 50 13 5.4167 \\ 51 15 6.2500 \\ 52 12 5.0000 \\ 53 11 4.5833 \\ 54 12 5.0000 \\ 55 18 7.5000 \\ 56 7 2.9167 \\ 57 14 5.8333 \\ 58 16 6.6667 \\ 59 5 2.0833 \\ 60 10 4.1667 \\ 61 1 0.4167 \\ 62 4 1.6667 \\ 63 3 1.2500 \\ 64 0 0.0000 \\ 65 1 0.4167 \\ 66 0 0.0000 \\ 67 1 0.4167 \\ 68 0 0.0000 \\ 69 0 0.0000 \\ 70 0 0.0000 \\ 71 1 0.4167 \\ };
    \addplot table[header=false,row sep=\\] { 30 2 0.8333 \\ 31 1 0.4167 \\ 32 2 0.8333 \\ 33 4 1.6667 \\ 34 4 1.6667 \\ 35 3 1.2500 \\ 36 4 1.6667 \\ 37 6 2.5000 \\ 38 5 2.0833 \\ 39 7 2.9167 \\ 40 19 7.9167 \\ 41 17 7.0833 \\ 42 15 6.2500 \\ 43 18 7.5000 \\ 44 11 4.5833 \\ 45 17 7.0833 \\ 46 17 7.0833 \\ 47 14 5.8333 \\ 48 10 4.1667 \\ 49 11 4.5833 \\ 50 8 3.3333 \\ 51 11 4.5833 \\ 52 2 0.8333 \\ 53 7 2.9167 \\ 54 11 4.5833 \\ 55 3 1.2500 \\ 56 4 1.6667 \\ 57 1 0.4167 \\ 58 1 0.4167 \\ 59 2 0.8333 \\ 60 2 0.8333 \\ 61 0 0.0000 \\ 62 0 0.0000 \\ 63 0 0.0000 \\ 64 1 0.4167 \\ };
    \legend{Group C, Group D}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, just putting two plots side by side is much simpler than matrix was, and maybe even simpler than groupplot.  Any idea how to automatically calculate bar width so I can use ybar for the right-hand plot (just on principle, histograms ought to be bars, now it is kinda-sorta a density function) without having the bars all overlap?  I will be making four figures just like this, and the range of sparsity will vary in each one.  So a single setting that autoconfigures the bar width would be awesome.

Comment: Or I could use ybar intervals and keep the number of bars low.  Hmmm...

Comment: @BenVoigt I am not professional in latex or even pgfplots. But I read the pgfplots manual so much. You can find very good examples in it.

Comment: @BenVoigt You can edit bar width by adding `bar width=25,` to `[ybar stacked, [...]` part.